# Why a frequent word gets misclassified?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

I am practising NLP and checking using the below function what are the most frequent words per category and then observe how some sentences would be classified. The results are surprisingly wrong (Do you have to suggest another way of doing this helpful part of finding most frequent words per category?):

```
#The function
def show_top10(classifier, vectorizer, categories):
...     feature_names = np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
...     for i, category in enumerate(categories):
...         top10 = np.argsort(classifier.coef_[i])[-10:]
...         print("%s: %s" % (category, " ".join(feature_names[top10])))

#Using the function on the data
show_top10(clf, vectorizer, newsgroups_train.target_names)

#The results seem to be logical
#the most frequent words by category are these:
rec.autos: think know engine don new good just like cars car
rec.motorcycles: riding helmet don know ride bikes dod like just bike
sci.space: don earth think orbit launch moon just like nasa space

#Now, testing these sentences, we see that they are classified wrong and not based 
#on the above most frequent words

texts = ["wheelie", 
    "stars are shining",
    "galaxy"]
text_features = vectorizer.transform(texts)
predictions = clf.predict(text_features)
for text, predicted in zip(texts, predictions):
   print('"{}"'.format(text))
   print("  - Predicted as: '{}'".format(newsgroup_train.target_names[predicted]))
   print("")
```

and the results are:

```
"wheelie"
  - Predicted as: 'rec.motorcycles'

"stars are shining"
  - Predicted as: 'sci.space'

"galaxy"
  - Predicted as: 'rec.motorcycles'
```

The word **galaxy** is mentioned many times in the space texts. Why it can't classify it correctly?

The code of the classification can be seen below if needed.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics


cats = ['sci.space','rec.autos','rec.motorcycles']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                           remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',
                           remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), categories = cats)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 1000,max_df = 0.5,
                            min_df = 5, stop_words='english')


vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)

vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)

clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=.01)
clf.fit(vectors, newsgroups_train.target)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
```

Maybe is due to the fact that the accuracy score is 0.77 which renders some to be misclassified. How do you suggest to make the model to perform better? Actually SVM would be what I would like to use but gives worse results and gives as more frequent words just "00" in every category.

Comment: This is very similar to your earlier question. Are you going to ask a separate question for each term? Did you look into how often "galaxy" occurs in the `rec.motorcycles` posts? (Quick googling indicates that it is prevalent in the email address of a frequent contributor, but I have not investigated properly.)

Comment: hahaha. Don't let the fact that it is about the same code trick you. The other question was about a wrong variable. I don't know if the email that you said matters because I have removed the headers, footers, etc I am learning using tutorials and I would appreciate some help on what practises can be improved here to get better accuracy.

Comment: @tripleee Can you suggest ways to increase accuracy in svm?

Comment: If the word is not a good differentiating indicator, hacking the algorithm is just going to make overall results worse. Look at your data first.

Comment: removing these is part of the data cleaning process and is suggested in the documentation of the scikit learn. I have checked the data before posting but the weird thing is that only in the space category was existing. I even tried "andromeda galaxy" and it got classified in the "motorcycle" class again.

Comment: Does `remove=('quotes')` also remove the text *before* a quote, like "rob at galaxy edu wrote:"?

Comment: this remains if I understand correctly. I checked with ctrl + f and the only "galaxy" is from space text nothing else. You can use the code from the question to check anything you want. Furthermore by trying the svm reutns "00" as more frequent words. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The frequent words get mis-classified because you are not training with the frequent words, rather you are training with vectorized documents. The problem you describe is a text classification problem, i.e assigning a label to a piece of text (here news articles).

The way you are training is that you are making a vector for each document using [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) and you have specified `max_features = 1000`.

Naturally during training you are providing a lot of text to the vectorizer, which produces a dense vector.

During testing you are trying to extract 1000 features from two-three words! This results in very sparse vectors. Even though they include frequent words, whose weights might be high, the frequent words don't contribute enough to the total mass of the weights of 1000 features. So the classifier does not have enough features with high weights to predict.

I think this explains why the texts are mis-classified. If you want to experiment I'll suggest reducing the no. of features and instead of feeding the whole text during training, feed top-n frequent words.

Comment: I tried decreasing that number and it got way worse in accuracy. Have you tried to see if your theory improves the result? You can test this very easily since the example I have provided is reproducible.